# Get specified row from database using PHP PDO / Function

Tags: php, pdo

I have problems to display others rows from database with next code. When i type `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` i get username of logged in user on *home.php*, but when i want to display user company for example from database using same code `<?php echo $_SESSION['company']; ?>` i don't get that row on *home.php*. My code look like this:

**config.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

define('DBHOST','host');
define('DBUSER','user');
define('DBPASS','pass');
define('DBNAME','dbname');

define('DIR','localhost');
define('SITEEMAIL','email@host.com');

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

**user.php**

```
<?php
    include('password.php');
    class User extends Password{

        private $_db;

        function __construct($db){
            parent::__construct();

            $this->_db = $db;
        }

        private function get_user_hash($username){

            try {
                $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID FROM tableName WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
                $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

                return $stmt->fetch();

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
            }
        }

        public function login($username,$password){

            $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

            if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

                $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
                return true;
            }
        }

        public function logout(){
            session_destroy();
        }

        public function is_logged_in(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
    require('includes/config.php');
    if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }
?>
```

In body when i want to display information of user i type this line code:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?> **WORKING**

<?php echo $_SESSION['company']; ?> **NOT WORKING**
```

I think problem is to some function or need to create another one for retrive all fields from database, but if someone can help me that will be great. Thanks all

Comment: Where you set value for `$_SESSION['company']`?

Comment: On page `user.php` on function `public function login($username,$password)` i add `$_SESSION['company'] = $row['company'];` and still nothing @Saji

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below updatated `user.php`. The problem is, you are not selecting the column `company` from `db` and not setting the session.

```
<?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, company FROM tableName WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" '); //included the column company
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function login($username,$password){

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
            $_SESSION['company'] = $row['company']; //Added this line
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }
}

?>
```